# Make <ul> list items fill div completely

Tags: html, css, list

I have a unordered list, which is inside a `div` element. The goal is to make list elements fill the `<div>` from one side to the other perfectly.

Right now the left side is positioned just as I need, but I need the right side to look the same way. Hopefully you get the idea of what I mean.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rwroLh2/)

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="currency">
                <ul>
                    <li>Currency £</li>
                    <li>Sign in</li>
                    <li>My Account</li>
                    <li>My Gifts</li>
                    <li>My Basket</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**CSS code**

```
#currency{
    height: 11px;
    width: 360px;
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 11px;
    margin-right: 11px;
    line-height: 11px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: justify;
}
#currency ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
#currency ul li{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: That is not how to circumvent the requirements of posting an SO question. If you want to post a fiddle, post the code.

Comment: @Terry I agree completely but completely removing the JSFiddle link is _the worst_ way to correct the issue. Having the OP edit the code into their question is the best way to solve it but if they don't/won't, edit it in yourself

Comment: @Bojangles Alright, gotcha.

Comment: Tried to edit it, someone already did that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think want you want to achieve is using `text-align` properly.

```
#currency ul li{
    text-align: center;
}

#currency ul li:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}
#currency ul li:last-child {
    text-align: right;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rwroLh2/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but no, that's not what I'm trying to do. I need the letter "C" to touch the left side of the div, and the last elements last letter to touch the right side of the div.

Comment: yes, he just have some incorrection in the code see this: http://jsfiddle.net/5rwroLh2/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try the [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) model since it's meant for situations like this:

> The flex CSS property is a shorthand property specifying the ability
>   of a flex item to alter its dimensions to fill available space. Flex
>   items can be stretched to use available space proportional to their
>   flex grow factor or their flex shrink factor to prevent overflow.

```
#currency {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 11px;
    margin-right: 11px;
    line-height: 11px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#currency ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    width: 100%;
}
#currency ul li {
    flex-grow:2;
    text-align:center;
    margin:3px;
    background:#fc0;
    height:20px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5k36cdq1/)

All colors, paddings and margins were added in order to show how it works since your tiny example is very difficult to see